# How to make a C++ class that inherits from only one of two base classes at compile time?

Tags: c++, strategy-pattern

First time post.  This is a general question about how to do something in C++.  To not waste your time, I'll just ask it generalized.  But if your response is something like, "Why do you want to do something so stupid like that?", I'll give the details below.

**General Question**

I have a base class with common code (SPIBase).  I have two classes that inherit it that have significantly different implementations (SPIMaster, SPISlave).  In each of these two classes, I expose public/protected functionality that is identical.  I want to write a single class that **optionally** inherits from one of these two classes.  How should I go about doing that?

**Details**

I am building a library for some microelectronics (ESP8266).  I use the Arduino IDE, and the library is in C++.  As you might be familiar, SPI is a methodology/protocol for communicating between two micro-controllers or a micro-controller and something like a sensor.  A micro-controller is always a Master and the other device/sensor is always a Slave.  The Master completely controls the communication process in SPI.  The Slave is normally relatively passive.   I've written the library to work only between two ESP8266 micro-controllers to form a TCP/IP like protocol where either can send a message to the other un-solicited.  Basically, the Master/Slave issues are hidden and the developer using the library can setup their protocol any way they prefer and in either direction.  (i.e.  Client/Server/Peer messaging, send/response, Streams, etc).  Although, Master/Slave issues are hidden, obviously, one ESP8266 must use one base implementation and the other ESP8266 must use the other.

I now want to write the layer that implements Streams / File transfers.  This class will ride on one or the other of the two intermediate classes, but will be identical except in which class they inherit.  They both will be both senders and receivers.  I'd rather not have two complete classes that are really identical in their implementation.  In this case, I don't really want any portion of one chain of code to be on the other device.  My original thought proved after research not to be possible was to basically... have the library using developer use #define MASTER or #define SLAVE in their main program file and the streaming class would inherit one or the other classes based on this.  I soon discovered that #defines aren't visible downstream.  
Is there some C++ design methodology / pattern that will get the results I want?  
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where do you want to decide which class is inherited? Instead of so many words, could you write some pseudo-code that would explain your intentions?

Comment: Wow!  That was quick response.  I would like the decision outside of the library's code base.  Many developers on the Arduino are not interested in the how libraries work... just that they do.  They don't want to hunt inside that code base to figure how to toggle it.  I want some compile time flag placed in the user's main program to compile one inheritance hierarchy or the other.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Most forums let me add another post as most people don't like the original question to be changed.  I can only seem to "Answer Your Question" or add a comment.  And I can't seem to format inside this "Add Comment".  I'd like to add the pseudo code example as you suggested.  How is that best done on this site?

Comment: @Inq, you should edit your question if you want to add information.  That's normal on this site (which terms itself as a Q&A site and not a forum).  Did you consider templates?  If so, I'll suggest you to add why this isn't acceptable.

Comment: Can't you construct the inherited classes in your library and pass them opaquely to your library's users? That way you don't have to worry about them doing the inheritance correctly.

Comment: @AProgrammer - Little rusty on Templates.  Let me check into that.

Comment: @Richard - I can create two classes SPIStreamMaster and SPIStreamSlave, but they would be identical except the one line in the header file:  class SPIStreamMaster : public SPIMaster and that repeat of code base is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Inq: You'd use inheritance or templates to avoid the duplication and then only expose the derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use templates.  For example:

```
template <typename SPIImpl>
class SPIStream : public SPIImpl
{
    // stream implementation using the common interface
};
```

You would then declare an instance of the class like this:

```
SPIStream<SPIMaster> spi_master_stream;
```

OR

```
SPIStream<SPISlave> spi_slave_stream;
```

Comment: Thanks all!  Templates is definitely what I need.